# Weird Error with certain filename in php

Tags: php

I am having a really weird error, I have this template Engine (which I think is working correctly since it shows most files correctly):

```
<?php

class Template
{
protected $template;
protected $vars = array();

public function __construct($template)
{
    $this->template=$template;
}
public function __get($key)
{
    // TODO: Implement __get() method.
    return $this->vars[$key];
}
public function __set($key, $value)
{
    // TODO: Implement __set() method.
    $this->vars[$key]=$value;

}
public function __toString()
{

    extract($this->vars);
    chdir(dirname($this->template));
    ob_start();
    include basename($this->template);

    //echo $this->template;

    return ob_get_clean();


}

}
```

Then I have this file named topic.php with the following code in it:

```
<?php
require ('core/init.php');
$template = new Template("templates/topic.php");
echo $template;
?>
```

And my template "templates/topic.php" looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "Testo";
```

And finally I have this other file  "templates/test.php" which looks like this:

```
<?php
echo "Testing";
```

If in line two of topic.php I change $template = new Template("templates/topic.php"); to $template = new Template("templates/test.php"); 
It just prints correctly, "Testing" shows in the webpage but if I want to show "templates/topic.php" it doesn't show anything in the webpage. Also if I refactor "templates/topic.php" to "templates/topici.php" for example, it works fine.

This is not a project I need to deliver and the workaround is really simple... is not to use  the file name  topic.php in the template directory, but I want to understand what is happening.

Note: Also, I have other files with a similar structure where for example the file is named "create.php" and the file it is supposed to show is "templates/create.php" and they all work fine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should be getting errors left and right based on the code you've provided. Make sure to set `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` at the beginning of these files you've mentioned and update your question with any relevant errors.

Comment: Are you testing this on a hosting service like "one.com"? (they have a long-living-cache, changes in code can take upto 20 minutes to be reflected when calling the URL. Guess other hosters use a similiar system) (Saying: FOR SURE it has nothing to do with certain filenames, but if the same content works in another filename - it's a corrupted cache(d) content nothing more)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus:  `__toString()` takes care of that.

Comment: @dognose I'm using xampp it is not online I'm just playing with code. I already tried deleting cache and restarting the server.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  as AbraCadaver said __toString() takes care of that, just to test I had set it manually but it stills happens the same.Also if I just go to http://localhost/../../templates/topic.php instead of http://localhost/../../topic.php it displays the code correctly.